# If user found in a post it returns the username from User database as permalink in the post from models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is my class models.py I have tried the .split method but keep getting an error that Charfield can not iteriet. I'm trying to make it so that when I call posts in a template if there is a username starting with @ it will have the username link to that users profile.

```
class Status1(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=333)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Your question is not obvious. Show what exact you tried and it doesn't work, and what the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You use the below statement for your purpose:

```py
{% if val|slice:":1" == '@' %}
   #Doing stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply does this go in the models.py or the template?

Comment: This code should be used in your templates. when this statement goes true, means val variable starts with @

Comment: In my template I have the post model as {{ post.post }} and the code you gave me can't directly effect the post in the template that's why I was asking if I could do this in the models section... thank you for your help so far your great!

Comment: @hauntboy You can use {% if post.user.username|slice:":1" == '@' %}